# What is the matter with those backslashes in python f-string expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, f-string

I am trying to wrap my head around the "no backslashes in f-string expressions" thing (also see [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue27921).

When in a python session we cannot use backslashes in the expression part of an f-string:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> f'{a \
... + 1}'
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

When I am inside an IPython session, on the other hand things work fine (try this out e.g. [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/)):

```
In [1]: a = 1
In [2]: f'{a \
   ...: + 1}'
Out[2]: '2'
```

I don't see what the issue with backslashes in python are: if it doesn't seem to bother IPython why does it bother the interpreter?

Comment: Because IPython joins the lines internally before giving them to the compiler.

Comment: I assume that! But how is something similarly simple not possible from within Python itself.

Comment: DId you read the long discussion that Eric cites in https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-August/145979.html?

Comment: The examples of banned backslashes in the PEP escape quotes.  It's possible that the line continuation backslash wasn't considered or included in the discussion (I haven't read the full discussion), but that banning ALL backslashes was the simplest quick fix that Eric alludes to.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue30793 continues this discussion, including a mention of jupyter's handling (or possible mishandling) of the continuation backslash.

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-August/041812.html - the f-literal developer sought, at least in PY 3.6, to take the conservative route, prohibiting all backslashes.  He reasons that easing a restriction in the future is easier than tightening it.